# JavaMail: Unable to send SMTP mail for domain transferred to Google Apps

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, google-apps

I have recently moved my emails to Google Apps. now I can see and send mails through login to my email account on gmail.com.

sales@example.com, now I am trying to send SMTP emails which was working fine with previous SMTP settings on older hosting.

here is my code

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("sales@example.com", "my-new-password-on-gmail");
            }
        });
```

and here is the error I see

```
EHLO 192.168.56.1
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [xxx.xx.xxx.xx an ip address]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtb
534-5.7.14 bABxM5_Dmk2f4asdasd86czsyvAdPqDTVjasdasdR2uN3N
534-5.7.14 bZAMByd76RlHwaGfasdasdoMS4pvXFhJOeoGhTwfRXWU2csadasd-zsuhCGiH7LUJsvrP_
534-5.7.14 DGJ_H79hQJlasdasdXNk0q_lRiiSGjDxsum4cZqQ6asdasdasdasdasdefI3-GjhEXGqCi5g
534-5.7.14 fZk_9lOFdPY9asduyernmdfhdfwm-k> Please log in via your web browser and
534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 n13oiuy5458013wmd.3 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:826)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:761)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:685)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.vdif.web.commons.SmtpMailSender.send(SmtpMailSender.java:104)
    at com.vdif.web.commons.SmtpMailSender.send(SmtpMailSender.java:33)
    at com.vdif.web.commons.SmtpMailSender.main(SmtpMailSender.java:116)
```

Comment: Login was denied. Have you granted access to the APP? Follow the link in the error message and do what is recommended there: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754

Comment: Well I am unable to rectify the problem, What is the way to make above communication secure, I have added gmail certificate in java security scert
`"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/security/cacerts"`

Comment: openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465 > sampe.txt
and then from this txt file I separated the certificate

Comment: I do not think the Cert is the problem. Did you make sure you have the correct client token etc. Try to login in a webbrowser, then start your client.

Comment: did that but no luck

Comment: You should fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), but that's not the source of your problem.  Nor is the certificate.  You need to login via a web browser running on the same machine that your application is running on.  If that's not possible, you'll probably need to switch to [OAuth authentication](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2).

Answer (score 0):

Port no. 465 is for SSL enabled (smtps). Its properties goes as below:

```
        properties.put("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtps.port", "465");
        properties.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
```

for port no. 587

```
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", TRUE);
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.required", TRUE);
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "false");
        properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
```

It works.!